# Given two strings, base and remove, return a version of the base string where all instances of the remove string have been removed

Tags: java, string

Given two strings, `base` and `remove`, return a version of the `base` string where all instances of the `remove` string have been removed (not case sensitive).

You may assume that the remove string is length 1 or more. Remove only non-overlapping instances, so with `"xxx"` removing `"xx"` leaves `"x"`. 
For example,

```
withoutString("Hello there", "llo") → "He there"
withoutString("Hello there", "e") → "Hllo thr"
withoutString("Hello there", "x") → "Hello there"
```

But Im failing most of the test cases here in codingbat. Could anybody please help me?

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {

   String result = "";
   for(int i = 0; i < base.length() - remove.length(); i++){
      if(!(base.substring(i, i + remove.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(remove))){
         result += base.substring(i, i + 1);
      }
      else{
         i = i + remove.length();
      }
   }

   return result;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you set up these tests on your local PC and debug them to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: We can provide an answer - but you won't learn from it... Instead I can give you the following tip: instead of `for` loop use `while (i < base.length())` and manually increment `i` appropriately (if-case will require different increment than the else-case).

Comment: There are a *lot* of answers on this very question here, actually...were you not interested in any of their solutions, and you wanted to pioneer your own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you read anything else in this answer, note that you should read this article:

### [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

It will help you to solve problems like this one and in your future programming life. That said:

---

You have two problems with this code.

1. `i` increments one position *every time no matter what*. You are correct to want to advance it if a substring has not been found, but the problem is that you advance it too many spaces. So, instead of using `i + remove.length()`, instead use:

   ```
   i = i + remove.length() - 1;
   ```
2. You aren't properly adding the last bit of the string on at the end, if the *remaining string is shorter than the remove size*. This is why `THIS is a FISH` is breaking for you. You can include a special check for that, and then run to the end of the list, e.g.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < base.length(); i++) {
       if(i > base.length() - remove.length()) {
           result += base.substring(i, base.length());
           break;
   ```

Here is the complete program:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
  String result = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < base.length(); i++) {
    if (i > base.length() - remove.length()) {
      result += base.substring(i, base.length());
      break;
    } else {
      String substring = base.substring(i, i + remove.length());
      if (!(substring.equalsIgnoreCase(remove))) {
        result += base.charAt(i);
      } else {
        i = i + remove.length() - 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...

```java
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
    String result = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < base.length(); i += 1) {
        if ((i <= base.length() - remove.length()) && base.substring(i, i + remove.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(remove)) {
            i += remove.length() - 1;
        } else {
            result += base.charAt(i);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to solve this problem:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) { 
    return base.replaceAll("(?i)" + remove, "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function within String objects that can replace or remove string snippets using regular expresions.

```
public String remove(String base, String remove) {

  return base.replaceAll(getRegExp(remove), "");
}

private String getRegExp(String remove) {

  StringBuilder regExp = new StringBuilder();

  for (Character caracter : remove.toCharArray()) {
    regExp.append("[").append(Character.toLowerCase(caracter))
      .append(Character.toUpperCase(caracter)).append("]");
  }

  return regExp.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer works. Seems to be simpler though. looking forward to a better one.

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
  String str = "";
  for(int i = 0; i < base.length()-remove.length()+1;i++){
    if(base.substring(i,i+remove.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(remove)){
      base = base.substring(0,i)+base.substring(i+remove.length());
      i--;
    }
  }
  return base;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
  StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
  sb.append(base);
    while(sb.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(remove.toLowerCase())!=-1)
    sb.replace(sb.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(remove.toLowerCase()),sb.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(remove.toLowerCase())+remove.length(),"");
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: This is my solution using StringBuilder.

Comment: write your description in answer with edit not in comment

Answer (score 0):

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
  String newStr = "";
  int bLength = base.length();

      int rLength = remove.length();
      
      for (int i =0; i < bLength; i++){
        if (i <= bLength-rLength && base.substring(i, i+rLength).equalsIgnoreCase(remove){
          i += rLength-1;
          continue;
        }
        newStr += base.charAt(i);
      }
      return newStr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer for this question.

```
  public static String withoutString(String str, String D) {
    String temp = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        temp += str.substring(i, i+1);
        if (temp.length() >= D.length() && temp.substring(temp.length() - D.length() , temp.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(D)) {
            temp = temp.substring(0, temp.length() - D.length());
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```